# Existence of weak Schauder-basis for concrete example.

Tags: banach-spaces, schauder-basis

Consider *e. g.* $P(X)$, the space of probability measures over some compact metrisable space, $X$. This may be viewed as a WOT*-compact subspace of some dual Banach space $Y^{\ast}=(C(X),\|\cdot\|_{\infty})^{\ast}$, namely a certain closed subset of the unit ball: $\{\varphi\in Y^{\ast}:\|\varphi\|\leq1\wedge \varphi\geq 0\wedge\varphi(1)=1\}$. This is a compact polish space.

My question essentially has to do with such spaces. I now formulate the question a little abstractly, but keep in mind the above context.

**Question:** Let $Y$ be a Banach space. Consider a separable metrisable compact subset $B\subseteq Y^{\ast}$. Does $B$ possess a weak*-Schauder-Basis? That is, does there exist $(x_{n}^{\ast})_{n\in\omega}\subseteq B$, so that

$$\forall{x^{\ast}\in B:~}\exists{!(c_{n})_{n\in\omega}\subseteq\mathbb{C}:~}
    x^{\ast}=\sum_{n\in\omega}c_{n}x_{n}^{\ast}\quad(:=\text{WOT*-}\lim_{n}\sum_{k<n}c_{k}x_{k}^{\ast})$$

I know that not every separable Banach space has Schauder-basis. But here the situation is that of with separable subsets of (dual) Banach spaces viewed under WOT(*), and the search is for a weak${}^{\ast}$-basis.

Comment: Is my answer okay? If not feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the general question is **no**.

It is a result of Banach that [a basis for the weak topology is also a basis for the norm topology](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WRc3ciSmsMMC&lpg=PA230&ots=6sAAJRVENs&dq=weak%20schauder%20basis&hl=pl&pg=PA230#v=onepage&q=weak%20schauder%20basis&f=false). Now take a reflexive space $X$ without the approximation property (for instance, any subspace of $\ell_p$ where $p\neq 1,2,\infty$ which lacks the approximation property). The ball $B$ of $X$ is weakly* (=weakly) compact. It cannot have the property you want as otherwise $X$ would have a basis.

As for $P(X)$, have you tried Dirac deltas corresponding to points from a countable dense subset of $X$?

Comment: Yes: one sees immediately, that no atomless measure can be expressed as an infinite sum of point-measures.

Comment: No, this is not true in the weak*-topology. Actually, the weak* convex hull of Dirac delta measures is the whole unit ball of $C(X)^*$.

Comment: Yes, I know that the Krein-Millmann Theorem guarantees: $\partial\mathcal{B}^{\ast}_{1}(0)=\overline{\langle\partial_{e}\mathcal{B}^{\ast}_{1}(0)\rangle_{convex}}$. This nevertheless does not guarantee represenation as countable infinite sums. It is (trivially) in fact almost everywhere (in the sense of category) false, that a measure has representation as infinite sum of dirac-measures (all continuous measures), since every ctbl. infinite set under such measures has measure 0.